# Вывод информации из БД PostgreSQL в телеграм бот Aiogramm

Tags: python, postgresql, aiogram

У меня возникли затруднения с выводом таблицы PostgreSQL в Телеграмм бот.
Необходимо чтобы при любом слове бот отвечал, результатом выборки из БД.
По команде PRINT все без проблем выдается в консоль, однако если вставить функцию в вывод телеграм бота, выдает ошибку парсинга. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно решить данный вопрос

Код телеграмм бота.

```
import config
import logging
import asyncio
#from datetime import datetime
#from ya import viv
#from bd1 import BD1

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token=config.API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Привет!\nНапиши мне что-нибудь!")


@dp.message_handler(commands=['help'])
async def process_help_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Напиши мне что-нибудь, и я отпрпавлю этот текст тебе в ответ!")


#async def echo_message(msg: types.Message):
   # await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, msg.text)
#print(str(BD1.ss()))

@dp.message_handler()
async def subscribe(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Прииивет ", BD1.ss())
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Код функции выборки.

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost", port = 5432, database="bot", user="postgres", password="postgres")
cur = conn.cursor()
print("Database opened successfully")

class BD1:

    def ss():
        cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM subscr""")
        query_results = cur.fetchall()
        return (query_results)
```

Код ошибки

```
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-7' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:331> exception=BadRequest('Unsupported parse_mode')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 339, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 194, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 214, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "b1.py", line 31, in subscribe
    await message.reply("Прииивет ", BD1.ss())
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\types\message.py", line 995, in reply
    return await self.bot.send_message(
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 219, in send_message
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.SEND_MESSAGE, payload)
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 201, in request
    return await api.make_request(self.session, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 104, in make_request
    return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 78, in check_result
    exceptions.BadRequest.detect(description)
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py", line 137, in detect
    raise cls(description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Unsupported parse_mode
```

Comment: Скорее всего проблема может быть в том, что переменная `query_results` содержит кортеж, а боту нужна строка

Comment: А текст ошибки покажите, пожалуйста

Comment: А как можно было бы преобразовать кортеж в строку ?

Comment: Дополнил ппост, добавил код ошиьки

Comment: Давайте начнем с того, что определимся в каком виде вы хотите это все видеть в телеге

Comment: В любом возможном.

Comment: def ss():
  cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM subscr""")
  text = '\n\n'.join([', '.join(map(str, x)) for x in cur])
  return (str(text))

Comment: Попробовал так, все равно ошибка

Comment: Здесь не особо подходит Postgres. Все равно что банку открывать канцелярской пилой. Почему бы не заюзать более простую в использовании SQlite? + Ко всему используйте пожалуйста ORM. С ней работать одно удовольствие, особенно в питоне. Рекомендую SQLAlchemy

Comment: `...for x in cur.fetchall()]` Ну это из того, что прям в глаза бросается. И еще. Возьмите за правило результат работы `cursor.fetchall()` передавать в переменную, а потом уже с этой переменной работать. Дело в том, что для того, чтобы получить данные из курсора второй раз нужно либо перезапускать запрос еще раз либо возвращать курсор в нулевую позицию. А оно Вам надо?

Answer (score 2):

Самостоятельно нашел ошбику.

Итоговый код бота:

```
import config
import logging
import asyncio
from bd1 import BD1

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token=config.API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Привет!\nНапиши мне что-нибудь!")


@dp.message_handler(commands=['help'])
async def process_help_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Напиши мне что-нибудь, и я отпрпавлю этот текст тебе в ответ!")

@dp.message_handler()
async def subscribe(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Прииивет ")
    await message.reply(BD1.ss())
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Код функции:

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost", port = 5432, database="bot", user="postgres", password="postgres")
cur = conn.cursor()
print("Database opened successfully")

class BD1:

    def ss():
        cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM subscr""")
        query_results = cur.fetchall()
        text = '\n\n'.join([', '.join(map(str, x)) for x in query_results])
        return (str(text))
```

Всем спасибо за советы.

Comment: А в чем ошибка то была? )))

Comment: Отступы разные в коде бота, плюс неправильно выводил. :)

Comment: На правах доброго совета. Скачайте `PyCharm community`, он бесплатный и очень хорошо подсвечивает ошибки включая вот такие обидные косяки как не правильные отступы